# Tensorflow how to get value in training step

Tags: python, tensorflow

Assume that loss and trainning like below:

```
cross_entropy = tf.mul(diff, diff)
train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(cross_entropy)
```

I would like to get the weights and biases in training step, like:

```
  for i in range(1000):
    sess.run(train)
        if cross_entropy == (specific value like 0.1, 0.05):
            print(weight)
            print(bias)
```

Is there any way to achieve it in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The easiest way is to evaluate all ops in one `run` and operate at the results in python (I assume `weight` and `bias` are ops, if not, you need to extract them from your layers):

```
for i in range(1000):
   _, w_val, b_val, ce_val = sess.run([train, weight, bias, cross_entropy])
       if ce_val == 0.005:
           print(w_val)
           print(b_val)
```

Comment: Is ce_val an array? I tried it, but got ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Ah, sorry, I mismatched the order of ops vs results. Should be ok now.

Comment: Thanks. Really helpful for me.